# How to make dynamic changes in Arcgis JS map-component with React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am quite new to Arcgis-JS and React. As suggested [here](https://www.esri.com/about/newsroom/arcuser/react-arcgis/), I am using a functional component with the `useEffect` hook to integrate my map.

Now I want to display a line within my map when I click on a certain row of a list. On click I am fetching the appropriate coordinates to be displayed and storing them to a context-variable (`dbPageContext.currentGeom`).

The problem: When I want to display another line, the entire map-component has to re-render as I am passing the line-array-variable as a second argument to the `useEffect` hook.

```
const MapComp = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef();
  const dbPageContext = useContext(DbPageContext);


  useEffect(() => {
    const mainMap = new Map({
      layers: [layer],
      basemap: "arcgis-topographic", // Basemap layer service
    });

    const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    mainMap.add(graphicsLayer);

    const polyline = {
      type: "polyline",
      paths: dbPageContext.currentGeom, 
    };
    const simpleLineSymbol = {
      type: "simple-line",
      color: [0, 230, 250], 
      width: 4,
    };

    const polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
      geometry: polyline,
      symbol: simpleLineSymbol,
    });
    graphicsLayer.add(polylineGraphic);

    const view = new MapView({
      container: mapRef.current,
      map: mainMap,
      spatialReference: {
        wkid: 3857,
      },
    });
    return () => {
      view && view.destroy();
    };
  }, [dbPageContext.currentGeom]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="webmap" ref={mapRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapComp;
```

How can I update only the graphics-layer without updating the entire map-component? Would be great if someone  could help me finding a solution for that.

EDIT: I also tried to implement the map without using the `useeffect` hook. But then, nothing was displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the effects.  On page load, you should have one effect that creates the map.  Then a second effect can update the map when `dbPageContext.currentGeom` changes.

```js
const MapComp = () => {
  const mapRef = useRef();
  const dbPageContext = useContext(DbPageContext);

  // Memoize this, as you only need to create it once, but you also need
  // it to be available within scope of both of the following useEffects
  const graphicsLayer = React.useMemo(
    () => new GraphicsLayer(), 
    []
  );

  // On mount, create the map, view, and teardown
  useEffect(() => {
    const mainMap = new Map({
      layers: [layer],
      basemap: "arcgis-topographic", // Basemap layer service
    });

    const view = new MapView({
      container: mapRef.current,
      map: mainMap,
      spatialReference: {
        wkid: 3857,
      },
    });

    mainMap.add(graphicsLayer);

    return () => {
      view && view.destroy();
    };
  }, [])

  // When dbPageContext.currentGeom changes, add a polyline
  // to the graphics layer
  useEffect(() => {
    const polyline = {
      type: "polyline",
      paths: dbPageContext.currentGeom, 
    };
    const simpleLineSymbol = {
      type: "simple-line",
      color: [0, 230, 250], 
      width: 4,
    };

    const polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
      geometry: polyline,
      symbol: simpleLineSymbol,
    });
 
    // Clear previously added lines (if that's what you want)
    graphicsLayer.removeAll()
    graphicsLayer.add(polylineGraphic);
  }, [dbPageContext.currentGeom]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="webmap" ref={mapRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapComp;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

When I use your code I get the following error: 
[esri.views.LayerViewManager] Failed to create layerview for layer title:'no title', id:'18335ea7534-layer-1' of type 'graphics'.


Could you explain to me what that means?

Comment: Can you give more detail on the error stack trace?  What else does it say?  Esri's errors are usually pretty good

Comment: It says: `layerview creation failed` -> `Instance of 'esri.layers.GraphicsLayer' is already destroyed`. I found a thread with a similar problem [here](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-javascript-questions/adding-popuptemplate-on-graphic-in-the-sketch/td-p/1120397), where someone suggested downgrading the arcgis/core library to version 4.20. but this results in even more errors. If the graphicsLayer is already destroyed, i maybe should reinstantiate it at some place, but i don't know where to do that.

Comment: Problem solved by removing the `<React.StrictMode>`-Tag in my index.js file. Thank you so much @SethLutske for your help!